# Trying to delay spawn nodes using waitForDuration in didMoveToView with SpriteKit Scene (SWIFT) but not working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklabelnode

I'm trying to stop my nodes from falling just for a second or two at the start of my game. So my problem is when I push start the nodes are already halfway down the screen. I also tried changing how high the nodes start but it seems like a costly solution since I want to be careful not to let my FPS get too low. In my code I am trying to do this in the didMoveToView and I am using waitForDuration but it doesn't work.

[Example Image of Nodes Falling Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHk5X.png)

Any SpriteKit masters know what I should do? I'm using Swift. 
Here is my code:

```
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

            let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.5)
            let run = SKAction.runBlock {
                self.spawnNumbers()
            }
            numContainer.runAction(SKAction.sequence([wait, run]))
    }

func spawnNumbers() {

        let minValue = self.size.width / 8
        let maxValue = self.size.width - 36

        let spawnPoint = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxValue - minValue)))
        let action = SKAction.moveToY(-300, duration: 2)

        numContainer = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
        numContainer.name = "Circle"
        numContainer.size = CGSize(width: 72, height: 72)
        numContainer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        numContainer.position = CGPoint(x: spawnPoint, y: self.size.height)
        numContainer.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
        numContainer.zPosition = 2

        let numberLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AvenirNext-Bold")
        numberLabel.text = "\(numToTouch)"
        numberLabel.name = "Label"
        numberLabel.zPosition = -1
        numberLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(numContainer.centerRect) + 36, CGRectGetMidY(numContainer.centerRect) + 36)
        numberLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center
        numberLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .Center
        numberLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        numberLabel.fontSize = 28

        addChild(numContainer)
        numContainer.addChild(numberLabel)
        numContainerArray.append(numContainer)
        numToTouch += 1
    }
```

Comment: So this is Physics based? Also what were you going to say "since I want to be ca"?

Comment: @cocojoe the app is not physics based. (Fixed typo too.)

Comment: So `spawnNumbers()` starts the action for you and the only place it is called is in this action block? 
Why not use your action sequence after the player pushes your start button?
Kind of curious to your 'keep my FPS low' statement?

Comment: Show self.spawnNumbers()

Comment: FPS is frames per second. I said that because I DON'T want have low frames.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to cast the 2.5 seconds to an NSTimeInterval:

```
 let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2.5))
```

You could also try putting the actions in the `init` function for your scene:

```
 override init (size: CGSize) {
     super.init(size: size)

     //your code from before
 }
```

Also, not sure if it matters, but this is what I normally do and it works,

```
 let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2.5))
 let action = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.spawnNumbers()})
 let actionThenWait = SKAction.sequence([wait, action])
 self.runAction(actionThenWait)
```